# Couchbase Elasticsearch Connector Saving Checkpoint Same Bucket

Tags: elasticsearch, couchbase

Couchbase Elasticsearch Connector saves checkpoint information to same bucket which i replicate to Elasticsearch.

I want to configure connector to save checkpoint information to another bucket? I could not find anything about it in documentation

[Couchbase Elasticsearch Connector](https://docs.couchbase.com/elasticsearch-connector/4.0/index.html)

[image]

Comment: This is not possible with version 4.0 of the connector. Sounds like a reasonable request, so let's track it as [CBES-114](https://issues.couchbase.com/browse/CBES-114).

Comment: In the mean time, can you elaborate on why the checkpoint documents are causing problems? Maybe there's a workaround for the problem.

Comment: Thank you for helping. I store only one type in my bucket therefore i don't want to put another stuff in my bucket.After long running connector it can cause memory quota problem.  How much TTL of checkpoint data in bucket?

Comment: There is one checkpoint document for each of the 1024 (64 on macOS) virtual buckets (also known as "partitions") that make up a Couchbase bucket. Each document stores a single checkpoint identifying the most recent database change that was propagated to Elasticsearch. The documents do not grow over time. I think it only takes about 100 kilobytes to store *all* of the checkpoints. The documents stay in the bucket until you remove them with the `cbes-checkpoint-clear` command line tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you very much [@dnault](https://stackoverflow.com/users/611819/dnault)

https://issues.couchbase.com/browse/CBES-114

It can be configured by metadataBucket property.